# How to import all missing classes at once?

Tags: phpstorm, jetbrains-ide

I  removed the namespace prefix from many lines in a file.
Now I want to import the corresponding classes for each of the missing classes.

For example:

```
Route::get('route1', [\App\Http\Controllers\Controller1::class, 'route1']);
Route::get('route2', [\App\Http\Controllers\Controller2::class, 'route2']);
Route::get('route3', [\App\Http\Controllers\Controller3::class, 'route3']);
... many more different controllers ...
```

Then I removed the namespace:

```
Route::get('route1', [Controller1::class, 'route1']);
Route::get('route2', [Controller2::class, 'route2']);
Route::get('route3', [Controller3::class, 'route3']);
... many more different controllers ...
```

Now each `Controller` is highlighted suggesting me to import the right class when I hover over it. But can I import all at once instead of going one by one?

Comment: Check the Problems tool window: *if a batch fix is possible* then the option should be available there (under the light bulb icon). At very least it works with some inspections (e.g. from `array()` to `[]` style) if you use `Code | Inspect Code...`

Comment: Nice, when I click the bulb icon and I highlight one of the missing classes, there's a little arrow on the side and when I click on it it shows: `Fix all 'undefined class' problems in file` and it worked. thank you

Comment: Try this as well: 1) get the file back (so you have more than 1class to import). 2) Place the caret on such a place in a file 3) Invoke the quick fix/intentions menu (using a mouse on a light bulb or via `Alt+Enter` (on most keymaps)) 3) When the menu is shown, expand the submenu for the most appropriate item (`arrow right` is the easiest way) 4) AFAIK it should have the same "fix all occurrences..." option there as well. Try it.

Comment: Yes you are correct! The light bulb is to the left of the code so I did not notice it, but it's there as well and no need to open the Problems tab. thanks again